# Get Google user name when using OAuthWebSecurity in ASP.NET MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth, dotnetopenauth, google-oauth

I've created a standard boilerplate ASP.NET MVC 4 Internet project. When using OAuthWebSecurity to enable my web site to do social login with Facebook, I see how I can access the Facebook user name in the ExternalLoginCallback() action in the AccountController by accessing the AuthenticationResult's ExtraData:

```
    AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication( Url.Action( "ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl } ) );

    var facebookName = result.ExtraData["name"];
```

When logging in with Google, however, ExtraData contains only "email". Is it possible to get the Google user name? Am I missing a configuration tweak somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my answer here: [Plugging custom OAuth/OpenID providers](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pranav_rastogi/archive/2012/08/23/plugging-custom-oauth-openid-providers.aspx). This has been a known issue since August 2012 and as yet (DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet 4.2.2.13055, April 2013) has not been fixed.

The workaround is to write your own Google provider, and the blog post above includes a complete working example. It is then a simple matter to get the Google user name:

```
var googleName = result.ExtraData["firstName"] + " " + result.ExtraData["lastName"];
```